# Publisher Actions missing from computer

Tags: publisher-action

I have a user that cannot access publisher actions that used to appear on the Case object in the Feed tab on his computer.  When I log in as the user they appear and even when I get the user to log in on my computer they appear on his Feed on the Case object.

The User has reinstalled Chrome to no avail.
[image: Publisher Actions Missing]

Anyone seen this happen before?  I suspect it's a setting on his computer and not on the Salesforce platform that is the issue here.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Resetting the browser typically gets rid of these issues.